# Expansion of $\cos ^{-1}x$

Tags: limits

I have two similar questions. Both need the limit of $\cos^{-1}x$. How do I find it? What is its series expansion? I haven't been taught it, so is there some other method also? One of the questions was $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{(\cos^{-1}x)^2}.$$

Comment: If you want to stick to real values, you want a one-sided limit $x \to 1-$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\cos^{-1}x=2y\implies x=\cos2y$

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-\sqrt x}{(\cos^{-1}x)^2}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{\cos2y}}{(2y)^2}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\cos2y}{(2y)^2(1+\sqrt{\cos2y})}=\cdots$$

Use $\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$ and $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$

Comment: Nice, I did not think like that. Good.

Comment: BTW, in the denominator it should be $(2y)^2$

Comment: @Garvil, Hope you got the idea. Rectified the typo

Answer (score 0):

From $~\arccos'x=-\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~$ it follows that $~\arccos x=-\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~$. Now, by expanding

the integrand into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), simplifying it, and then switching the order of summation and integration, we arrive at the [Taylor series expansion for the $\arccos$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).